# Windows 7. Нехватка памяти и сброс в файл подкачки

Tags: windows, память

Не совсем по теме сайта...

Испытываю нехватку ОЗУ (3,5 ГБ). Основная нагрузка (источник проблем) идет с процессов, экземпляров одной из программ. В некоторый момент происходит заполнение ОЗУ и память ***всех*** процессов сбрасывается в файл подкачки. Даже если некий процесс потреблял несколько МБ, его аппетиты снижаются до 0,5 МБ. Начинаются жуткие тормоза, на восстановление нормальной работы уходит до нескольких минут.

Отсюда вопросы:

Можно ли ограничить перечень процессов, память которых будет сбрасываться на диск? В идеале, нужно сбрасывать только у "процессов-виновников". Или хотя бы исключить из этого списка некоторые процессы (`Firefox`, например)

Как работает схема сброса памяти при нехватке? Можно ли настраивать, управлять этим процессом? Если несложно, киньте ссылку на талмуд.

Comment: Я бы использовал программу для изменения приоритетов процесса. Программа запоминает, какой приоритет какой программе(процессу), и тогда уже выдает столько `RAM`'а, сколько нужно, а не столько сколько захочет программа. Это как вариант. Попробуйте увеличить файл подкачки, посмотрите на программы, которые "жрут" Вашу оперативную. Проверьте ПК на вирусы.

Comment: @Roman Kozin, дело не в вирусах. Знаю, какие программы кушают лишнее. Программы нужные. Может я что-то путаю, на по-моему, приоритет влияет только на нагрузку на процессор (процессорное время). Файл подкачки у меня = ОЗУ * 2

Comment: Может быть уместен какой-либо менеджер памяти, который Вам поможет разобраться с этим вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

На диск сбрасываются прежде всего те страницы, которые давно не использовались:

> Когда система приближается к одному из установленных лимитов на свободную память, она начинает эту память освобождать. Во первых система находит процессы, максимально превысившие свой **лимит на размер рабочего набора**. Для этих процессов запускается процесс «старения» страниц (aging), для определения какие из страниц меньше всего используются. После этого, самые старые страницы «подрезаются» в standby или modified список.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> В пейджфайл страница может попасть только из modified списка. В modified список — при подрезке редко используемых страниц у разросшихся приложений. После того, как страница сброшена, она остается в standby списке и перечитываться не будет. Память никогда не берется из standby списка, если еще есть free или zeroed (то есть кешированные данные никогда не выбрасываются, если еще есть страницы вообще без данных). Standby список имеет 8 уровней приоритета (которыми до некоторой степени может управлять как само приложение, так и Superfetch, осуществляющий динамическое управление приоритетами страниц на основе анализа реального использования файлов/страниц), если не остается вообще никакого выбора — винда первым делом выбрасывает кеш **самого низкого приоритета**.

из [Here be dragons: Управление памятью в Windows как оно есть](http://geektimes.ru/post/107607/)

Конкретно в случае FF - можете попробовать подрезать ему память вызовом [`SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237(v=vs.85).aspx). Или понизить ему приоритет. Или поискать какой-нибудь управлятор памятью (наверняка они есть, хоть и эффективность их сомнительна).

Но я бы на вашем месте просто докупил память. А еще лучше - поставил SSD. 
И забыл про проблему свопа и тормоза как страшный сон.